# Which is better for finding pow(a,b), in terms of complexity?

Tags: c++, function

Which is better in runtime?

```
for(i=0;i<n;i*=c) or for(i=0;i<n;i=pow(i,c))
```

I found out the below link that says complexity for pow() is O(log(N)).

[Built-in Power Function Complexity](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/60247/built-in-power-function-complexity)

Its still not very much clear to me in terms of comparison.
I had recently encountered this question in an interview.

Comment: They do different things, so comparing their runtime makes no sense.

Comment: Even without considering what `pow()` actually does, what do you think is faster: multiplying 2 numbers or calling a function that does more than multiplication and may or may not be inlined?

Comment: what the interview question was actually after is that `pow(x,y) == pow(x,y/2) * pow(x,y/2)` which saves (almost) half of the multiplications (and can be done multiple times until you end up with O(log(N))

Comment: @tobi303: Can I have some of what the interviewer was smoking?

Comment: @Bathsheba I never had an interview of that kind, so I have no idea what they are smoking

Comment: @tobi303: Perhaps it's a new thing. I haven't been a candidate for over 10 years,

Comment: @tobi303 Alternatively, they're just looking for basic understanding of the for loop - that pow() is run every loop, and it's almost certainly slower than *  (even if you don't know O(log(N))   Or that i will never != 0 in the first loop

Comment: @tobi303 Or that i will never != 0 in the first loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dastardly silly question, and setting aside the fact that the first loop is infinite and `for (i = 0; i < n; i = pow(i, c))` is computing `pow` multiple times for the oddest of reasons and could well be infinite too, I hope the interviewer revealed the types for `i`, `c`, and `n`, because that matters a lot.

`pow(x, y)` is normally implemented as `exp(y log x)`. Both `exp` and `log` are normally computed on a modern CPU using a Newton-Raphson type algorithm with certain starting points tabulated. The result normally pops out in a single digit number of clock cycles. I don't believe the assertion that `pow` is O(log(N)) is correct.

However that goes off for surprisingly small integral values, for reasons centred around floating point computations. *That* doesn't tend to matter for very many scientific calculations however, and in my opinion at least, the way computers evaluate `pow(x, y)` is one of the marvels of computer science. For such integral values, a hand-rolled algorithm will perform better in terms of precision, but the one you present can be improved from a naive O(N) using *exponentation by squaring* which, perhaps, is what the interviewer wanted you to say all along.